# Task Cancel exception for an api call in Xamain.Forms for iOS real device only

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am doing an app in which i am calling a web api. I am getting task cancel exception when i call the api in iPad/iPhone.But the response is fine in simulator and android devices.Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue.I am not able to fine where it is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure, you are connected to the same network in both the system, simulator utilises MAC network, while Phone uses its own.

Comment: Thank you saket for your response.All the networks are same. But I am not able to get response in iPad and iPhone only.Can you suggest me any solutions.

Comment: Do one thing, while creating HTTPClient don't use default handler, use Native handler that would be NSUrlSessionHandler

Comment: Thank you Saketh.I am new to Xamairn.iOS can you send me a same code if possible.

Comment: HI Saketh. An update related to this issue. I added httpClient.TmeOut for 5 minutes.Then i got response after 4 mins. But in android i got response after 5 sec of api call.Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: ok. Let me Give u some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Native Http Handler to see it improves.

Declare an interface.

```
  public interface IHttpHandler
    {
        HttpClient ReturnHandler();
    }

Implement it this way.
public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public HttpClient ReturnHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler()
                {
                });
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
                return client;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException ReturnHandler-->" + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException ReturnHandler-->" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ReturnHandler Exception-->" + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ReturnHandler Exception-->" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Use Xamarin forms inbuilt Dependency injection to utilise the interface I gave you to have HTTPClient with native handler.

If you don't know how to read [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection)